# Check The Date Using Regular Expressions In JavaScript And Converting According To The Given Type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, web-services

I have requirement that a text box is filled with a date using a JQuery Date-picker and the date will be entered in any format but when it passes to a JSON webservice,

- Date must be converted to the yy-mm-dd (ex. 2014-04-15) format.
- This must be done using Regular expressions in JavaScript. The RegEx
  must check the format and if it is in the right or wrong format the
  inserted date must be converted to the above mentioned format.

So how can I do that?

Comment: this is not possible, you must fix a format first. Then only we can write regex. A date like 12/12/11 is correct in any format.

Comment: is that yy-mm-dd or yyyy-mm-dd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**yyyy-mm-dd**

```
var reg=/^(?:(?!0000)[0-9]{4}[-](?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-](?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])[-](?:29|30)|(?:0[13578]|1[02])[-]31)|(?:[0-9]{2}))?$/;
```

**yy-mm-dd**

```
var reg=/^(?:(?!00)[0-9]{2}[-](?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-](?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])|(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])[-](?:29|30)|(?:0[13578]|1[02])[-]31)|(?:[0-9]{2}))?$/;
```

Comment: Can I change the regular expression as in the below `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`. It does the same thing. That's a requirement from one of custom webservice developed using ASP.Net.(an **asmx webservice**)?